# to make a link unclickable but visible by default

Tags: jquery

```
<li><a href="" class="close">Close</a></li>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".close").removeClass("active");
    });
</script>

<li><a href="" class="hello">Print...</a>
</li>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hello").removeClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

Here I am getting close link unclickable but visible by default. But I am not getting it for `class="hello"`. What is the reason for this?
Both codes are same, so I should get the output for the second one also.

Comment: what do you mean by ` close link unclickable `

Comment: Can you share the css of close and hello?

Comment: Use single ready function for both close and hello class after second `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".hello").click(function(event)
{
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".hello").click(function(){                              
        return false;
    });
```